# Kubernetes-Dashboard Pod is not working once we install using HELM

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

Kubernetes-Dashboard pod is not working once we install using HELM on GKE. Can some one helm on this and how we can able to access the dashboard from external

kubectl get po --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE   default

NAME        dashboard-demo-kubernetes-dashboard-6586b59d57-dxj6p

Ready:          0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   11         36m

Please find the below logs:

1. Synchronizer kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system exited with error: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system watch ended with timeout
2. panic: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:dashboard-demo-kubernetes-dashboard" cannot create secrets in the namespace "kube-system"

Answer (score 2):

It's permission issue to create a namespace and secret inside the cluster. You can use CRD (Custom resource definition) for the creation of service account and assign it.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
```

also you can find more at access control of dashboard at here github official helm chart : https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control

Comment: Thanks for your information. now my pod is working fine, but i am unable to access the dashboard from external. and in internal as well getting like "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\"",. Can you please help on this. This is the url which i am using in internal.                                                                                                  curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Comment: kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system |grep kubernetes                                                                      
kubernetes-dashboard-5478c45897-bzbxg                          1/1       Running   0          21m

Comment: which cloud provider are you using ?

Comment: can you try `kubectl get svc -n kube-system` then only try `curl localhost:8001/api`  or hit the `service name for dashboard`.

Comment: You can also try command `kubectl proxy` and then in your pc browser open `localhost:8001`

Comment: I am using GCP and i tried kubectl proxy as well but not able to access the dashboard from external. localhost:8001( Tried like this)

Comment: I am getting below error while accessing in local itself.curl  http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503

Comment: I think service expose issue